# No matching function for call, but why?

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, smart-pointers, default-constructor

I've nearly finished my smart pointer so I uploaded it to my univerity's website which runs a number of automated tests on my code.

The thing is I don't know what kind of tests are being excecuted. I am able to read the automated test's stdout which I did:

```
In instantiation of ‘my_pointer<T>::my_pointer() [with T = tester]’:
error: no matching function for call to ‘tester::tester()’
note: candidates are:
tester::tester(my_pointer<tester>)
candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
tester::tester(const tester&)
candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

So I'm guessing for some odd reason it won't invoke my my_pointer() constructor? This is my smart pointer class:

```
template<class T>
class my_pointer {
  T* raw_pointer;

public:
    my_pointer() {
        raw_pointer = new T();
        raw_pointer->incRefCnt();
    }

    my_pointer(T *obj) : raw_pointer(obj) {
        if(raw_pointer != NULL) raw_pointer->incRefCnt();
    }

    my_pointer(const my_pointer<T>& smart_pointer) : raw_pointer(smart_pointer.raw_pointer) {
        if(raw_pointer != NULL) raw_pointer->incRefCnt();
    }

    T& operator*() {
        return *raw_pointer;
    }

    T* operator->() {
        return raw_pointer;
    }

    operator T*() {
        return raw_pointer;
    }

    my_pointer<T> &operator=(const my_pointer<T> &smart_pointer) {
        if(this != &smart_pointer && raw_pointer != NULL) {
            /** if this was the last reference to the given memory address */
            if (raw_pointer->decRefCnt() == 0) {
                delete raw_pointer;                    
            }

            raw_pointer = smart_pointer.raw_pointer;
            raw_pointer->incRefCnt();
         }

        return *this;
    }

    bool operator== (const T* pointer) {
        return raw_pointer == pointer;
    }

    bool operator!= (const T* pointer) {
        return raw_pointer != pointer;
    }

    bool operator== (const my_pointer<T> &smart_pointer) {
        return raw_pointer == smart_pointer.raw_pointer;
    }

    bool operator!= (const my_pointer<T> &smart_pointer) {
        return raw_pointer != smart_pointer.raw_pointer;
    }

    ~my_pointer() {
       if(raw_pointer->decRefCnt() == 0 && raw_pointer != NULL) {
           delete raw_pointer;
       }
    }
};
```

This is a class, in which the references can be counted:

```
class refcounted {
private:
    int count;
public:
    refcounted() : count(0) { }

    int incRefCnt() {
        return ++count;
    }

    int decRefCnt() {
        return --count;
    }
};
```

Can you see any problems with the code? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's what it says.

You're doing `new T()` (i.e. `new tester()`), but there is no default constructor inside `tester`.

It is impossible to suggest solutions without knowing the assignment's constraints.

But, generally, you'd accept a `T*` into the smart pointer constructor so that the call site may be responsible for [dynamically] constructing it however is required. (An alternative would be a variadic template constructor, effectively mimicking standard "in-place" construction.)

You seem to be doing this already, so you could try removing the default constructor entirely… but clearly some part of the assignment requires it, otherwise it would not be being called.

Typically a default-constructed smart pointer would essentially do nothing. You could try that.

Comment: That was the problem, thank you. You really opened my eyes with this one :) I've only got one problem now: there is a null pointer exception or something similar somewhere in one test.

Comment: @masm64: That seems entirely unrelated to this particular question.

Comment: yea but I hate this automated stuff lel :)

Comment: @masm64: Then why don't you test your code yourself?

Comment: I don't know what the tests are. I think that the problem is with the dereferencing (dereferencing a null pointer).

Comment: @masm64: You don't need to know what someone else's tests are in order to write your own. How do you think we verify our programs in the real world? We don't just wait for someone else to use them then ask how it went. It seems ludicrous to me that you would submit your code for assessment without testing it!